# How do I correctly transform the utc time displacement from a date time string?

Tags: c++, qt

I use Qt with Version 4.6.2 and try to transform a custom date string with UTC time displacement information into a QDateTime object.

```
QString format = "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.zzz+hh:mm"
QDateTime dateTime = QDateTime::fromString("2017-10-18T08:30:02.000+01:00", format);
qDebug() << dateTime.toString(format);
```

The output is an empty string.

If I leave out the time displacement information in the format string and in the date string I get the date string as expected: 2017-10-18T08:30:02.000.

According to the [Qt documentation of QDateTime::fromString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatetime.html#fromString) there are no explicit format placeholders for the time displacement.

I also try the following

```
QDateTime dateTime = QDateTime::fromString("2017-10-18T08:30:02.000+01:00", Qt::ISODate); // ISO 8601
qDebug() << dateTime.toString(Qt::ISODate);
```

but the result is 2017-10-18T00:00:00.

So, how do I correctly  transform the utc time displacement from a date time string?

Comment: Useful? https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-11623

Comment: Interessting, thanks for your comment Tarod! Obvious its a Bug in Qt 4.6 and is fixed in Qt 4.7. I recognized that I use Qt with Version 4.6.2. So I will try to fix my problem above with the newer Qt version.

Comment: Great @kbisang! Let us know if you get what you want with a different Qt version.

Answer (score 1):

In case you'd need to stay with Qt 4.6 you can manually look for the displacement and add the difference if present:

```
QString strDate = "2017-10-18T08:30:02.000+01:00";
QStringList tokens = strDate.split('+');

QString format = "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.zzz"; // format without displacement
QDateTime dateTime = QDateTime::fromString(tokens[0], format);

if (tokens.count() == 2) { // input has displacement
  QString format = "hh:mm";
  int msecs = QTime::fromString(tokens[1], format).msecsSinceStartOfDay();
  dateTime = dateTime.addMSecs(msecs);
}

qDebug() << dateTime.toString(format);
```